# How to do Catalan Number with recursion in Excel?

Tags: excel, math, sum, catalan

I tried to the the following in Excel using N values:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/math/b/a/d/bad5db400fcfd7092e2008e376993a27.png

I can make the Ci using =COMBIN(2*N;N)/(N+1), but how to make n-i-1 considering my n >= 0 ?

Thanks

Comment: Do you want to use recursion or not? Because if you are using `Ci=COMBIN(2*N;N)/(N+1)`, that's not recursion at all.

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm asking, look at the picture (link)

Answer (score 0):

It's possible but it's sloppy because Excel doesn't easily allow you to have reversed arrays (eg, if you enter B5:B1, Excel will convert that to B1:B5).

For example, in pseudo-Excel notation

> C9 = C0*C8 + C1*C7 + C2*C6 + ... = "sumproduct(C0:C8, C8:C0)"

But C8:C0 is not allowed. To get something similar to C8:C0, we have to use the `offset` function.  You can google `offset` but here are some examples,

```
ROW(B4)-ROW(B$2:B4) = 4 - [2,3,4] = [2,1,0]
OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B4)-ROW(B$2:B4), 0, 3, 1) = OFFSET(B$2, [2,1,0], 0, 3, 1) = t[B4,B3,B2]
OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B4)-ROW(B$2:B4), 1, 3, 1) = t[C4,C3,C2]
OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B4)-ROW(B$2:B4), -1, 3, 1) = t[A4,A3,A2]
OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B4)-ROW(B$2:B4), 0, 2, 1) = t[B4,B3]
OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B4)-ROW(B$2:B4), 0, 1, 1) = t[B4]
```

Here is a sample worksheet to calculate the Catalan numbers using your formula:

```
   A    B
1  N   C_n
   --------
2  0   =1
3  1   =SUMPRODUCT(B$2:B2, N(OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B2)-ROW(B$2:B2),0,A3,1)))
4  2   =SUMPRODUCT(B$2:B3, N(OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B3)-ROW(B$2:B3),0,A4,1)))
5  3   =SUMPRODUCT(B$2:B4, N(OFFSET(B$2, ROW(B4)-ROW(B$2:B4),0,A5,1)))
6  4   cut-and-paste
```